# Operator precedence overloading in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any way to override operator precedence when overloading operators for custom classes? In my example, `+` should have higher priority than `*`. Can I override the default operator precedences?

```
class Vector{
    var x:Int
    var y:Int
    init(x _x:Int, y _y:Int){
        self.x = _x
        self.y = _y
    }
}

func *(lhs:Vector, rhs:Vector)->Int{
    return lhs.x * rhs.y + rhs.x + rhs.y
}

func +(lhs:Vector, rhs:Vector)->Vector{
    return Vector(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
}

var v1 = Vector(x: 6, y: 1)
var v2 = Vector(x: 3, y: 1)


v1 * v2 + v1
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. If you mean, do one thing first and then the second, you could use parenthesis. Please clarify your question if my answer doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe you can, but it would make your code harder to read, right? Because everybody has a preconceived notion that * has a higher precedence than +.

Comment: Operator precedence can only be overridden globally, which means that, wow, this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm. It actually appears that you can.

```
operator infix + { associativity left precedence 140 }
operator infix * { associativity left precedence 30 }

let x = 3 + 4 * 5 // outputs 35
```

But as far as I can tell, this can only be done at "file scope", at least according to a compiler error produced by including this within a class.

> 'operator' may only be declared at file scope.

Comment: Could you explain the numbers?

Comment: But this will apply globally, not just for that particular overload, won't it?

Comment: @Mohsen I basically chose them randomishly. I only came up with 140 because that's what Apple uses in an example in their book, and 30 just because it's.. well.. less. The default value is 100 if not specified.

Comment: @Chuck Yes, I believe so. Need to do more checking.

Comment: I can only set this at the top of my playground file, above the import statements, and before any use of the operators

Answer (score 5):

Answer to @Mohsen 's question

From the publicly available docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-XID_708), and under fair use:

```
Exponentiative (No associativity, precedence level 160)
        << Bitwise left shift
        >> Bitwise right shift

Multiplicative (Left associative, precedence level 150)
        * Multiply
        / Divide
        % Remainder
        &* Multiply, ignoring overflow
        &/ Divide, ignoring overflow
        &% Remainder, ignoring overflow
        & Bitwise AND

Additive (Left associative, precedence level 140)
        + Add
        - Subtract
        &+ Add with overflow
        &- Subtract with overflow
        | Bitwise OR
        ^ Bitwise XOR

Range (No associativity, precedence level 135)
        ..< Half-open range
        ... Closed range

Cast (No associativity, precedence level 132)
        is Type check
        as Type cast

Comparative (No associativity, precedence level 130)
        < Less than
        <= Less than or equal
        > Greater than
        >= Greater than or equal
        == Equal
        != Not equal
        === Identical
        !== Not identical
        ~= Pattern match

Conjunctive (Left associative, precedence level 120)
        && Logical AND

Disjunctive (Left associative, precedence level 110)
        || Logical OR

Ternary Conditional (Right associative, precedence level 100)
        ?: Ternary conditional

Assignment (Right associative, precedence level 90)
        = Assign
        *= Multiply and assign
        /= Divide and assign
        %= Remainder and assign
        += Add and assign
        -= Subtract and assign
        <<= Left bit shift and assign
        >>= Right bit shift and assign
        &= Bitwise AND and assign
        ^= Bitwise XOR and assign
        |= Bitwise OR and assign
        &&= Logical AND and assign
        ||= Logical OR and assign
```

Comment: Precedence levels can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016054